# how to control font and paragraph formatting in margins

Tags: xetex, formatting, margins, paragraphs, marginpar

i'm having a hard time to figure out how to control the exact appearance of margin text (such as is output by the `\marginpar` command). i'm using XeLaTeX with packages such as `geometry`, `fontspec`, `leading` and have managed to gain fine control over issues such as font faces, font sizes, paragraph indentation and line spacing, including how to set margin width and the distance of the margins from the main text.

how can i control the font and paragraph formatting of margins?

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX kernel uses `\@marginparreset` to set a fresh state in margin paragraphs. The usual definition is

```
\def\@marginparreset{%
  \reset@font
  \normalsize
  \@setminipage
}
```

and you can modify it setting the font you prefer. I'd suggest something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\@marginparreset{%
  \reset@font
  \normalsize
  \@marginparfont
  \@setminipage
}
\def\@marginparfont{\normalfont\itshape} % or whatever
\makeatother
```

With `\normalfont` you go in the default state and then you can add whatever specification you wish.

Comment: your answer implies using `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` to allow for command names containing ``@``, right?

Comment: @flow Yes; the two commands are not necessary only in `.sty` or `.cls` files.

Answer (score 0):

@egreg wow that was real fast, many thanks for your suggestion. i've had an idea in the meantime and came up with this:

```
\newcommand{\marge}[1]{\marginpar{\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\leading{2.5mm}#1}}
```

(i'm using `\leading` here coz `\fontsize` on its own would not appear to set the line height right).

so far the above seems works to my satisfaction—is anyone aware of possible ungood side effects?

Comment: `\leading` probably corrects it but `\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}` sets a 2mm font on the same baseline, it's unusual to use mm for font sizes but no harm in it, but normally the baselineskip should be  around 20% bigger than the font size. You then need `\selectfont` (which `\leading` also does) before `\fontsize` has any effect.

Comment: the thing is that the second argument to `\fontsize` would not appear to have any effect at all (pending more experiments), which is why i'm using `\leading` at all.

Comment: If you follow it by `\selectfont` and the paragraph ends within the scope of the change then it will have an effect, the whole of LaTeX's font machinery relies on that working...